# Replace missing value with cell above in either Perl or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, perl, csv

I'm importing a csv file of contacts and where one parent has many children it leaves the duplicated values blank. I need to make sure that they are populated when they reach the database however.

Is there a way that I can implement the following when I'm importing a .csv file into Perl and then exporting into MySQL?

if (value is null)

value  = value above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you place the individual values you read from the CSV file into an array (e.g. @FIELD_DATA). Then when you encounter an empty field while iterating over a row (e.g. for column 4) you can write

unless (length($CSV_FIELD[4])) {
      $CSV_FIELD[4] = $FIELD_DATA[4]
   }

Answer (score 0):

Not with an import statement afaik. You could, however, make use of triggers (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). Keep in mind though, that this will seriously impact the performance of the import statement.

Also: if they are duplicate values you should have a critical look at your database model or your setup overall.